# PresentViewController is not working in objective c. App is crashing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertcontroller, presentviewcontroller

When I am trying to present alert view controller my app is crashing.

```
-(void)setupAlertCtrl{
    self.alertCtrl=[UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Select Image"
                                                       message:nil
                                                preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

}
- (IBAction)selectImagePressed {
    **[self presentViewController:self.alertCtrl
                       animated:YES
                     completion:nil];//this funcanility is breaking**

}
```

**Exception** :

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Please Share your crash Log.

Comment: check 'self' is referring to some view ?

Answer (score 1):

**libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException**

This could also happen if you've wired up a button to an IBAction that doesn't exist anymore (or has been renamed)"

If you're running into this problem than go to your storyboard, RIGHT click on the yellow box icon (view controller) at the top of the phone outline and DELETE the outlet(s) with yellow flags.

What happens in instances like this is you probably named an action, then renamed it.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

This code will definitely help you.
**I suspect you are using iPad(normal action sheet crashes in iPad)**

```
-(void)setupAlertCtrl
{        
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {    
        UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil message:@"Your message" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

        // Remove arrow from action sheet.
        [alertController.popoverPresentationController setPermittedArrowDirections:0];
        //For set action sheet to middle of view.
        CGRect rect = self.view.frame;
        rect.origin.x = self.view.frame.size.width / 20;
        rect.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height / 20;
        alertController.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view;
        alertController.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = rect;
        
        [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];    
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil message:@"Your message" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
        [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to call the below function  in view did load

```
-(void)setupAlertCtrl
```

Then you can open the alert on button click

Answer (score 0):

You should have to write it like,

```
-(void)setupAlertCtrl
 {
     self.alertCtrl=[UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Select Image"
                                               message:nil
                                        preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
     [self presentViewController:self.alertCtrl animated:YES completion:nil];
 } 

-(IBAction)selectImagePressed 
{
    [self setupAlertCtrl];
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: its working fine at my end without any crashed so kindly check your side about IBAction connection with button in your storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

`UIAlertController` is a functionally identical, block-based replacement for both `UIAlertView` and `UIActionSheet`. Switching between an alert or action sheet is done by setting the preferred style when creating the controller.

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController
                              alertControllerWithTitle:alertTitle
                              message:alertMessage
                              preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I hope this will help you...

Answer (score 0):

Its not crashing, 
Just call the `SetupAlertCntrl` in `viewDidLoad` method. 
Its working fine

Comment: I think... you have taken a weak reference of your alertController..
Make that property strong,nonatomic

Comment: its breaking on presentviewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your alertController exist or not first, if not let created it first. One more thing, UIAlertControl only can present from UIViewController so, make sure self in selectImagePressed function is kind of UIViewController.

```
- (IBAction)selectImagePressed {
        if(self.alertController == nil) {
         [self setupAlertCtrl];
        }
        [self presentViewController:self.alertCtrl
                           animated:YES
                         completion:nil];//this funcanility is breaking**

    }
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
-(void)setupAlertCtrl
{
    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Choose Profile Image " message:@" " preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

     UIAlertAction* cameraAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Take Photo" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
         NSLog(@"Camera Action");
    }];
    [alertController addAction:cameraAction];

    UIAlertAction* gallaryAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Gallary" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
        NSLog(@"Gallary Action");
    }];
    [alertController addAction:gallaryAction];

    UIAlertAction* Cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:nil];
    [alertController addAction:Cancel];

    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

// Button Click action

```
 - (IBAction)selectImagePressed:(id)sender 
   {

    [self setupAlertCtrl];

   }
```

hope this will help you.